# How to fetch/get Google cloud transfer job's run history details in python?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-cloud-storage

I have few Google cloud transfer jobs running in my GCP account, which transfers data from Azure to GCS bucket.

As per this document - https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/reference/rest/v1/transferJobs/get?apix_params=%7B%22jobName%22%3A%22transferJobs%2F213858246512856794%22%2C%22projectId%22%3A%22merlincloud-gcp-preprod%22%7D
the "get" method can fetch details of the job like name, description, bucketName, status, includePrefixes, storageAccount and so on.

Here's the sample output of "get" method.

```
{
  "name": "transferJobs/<job_name>",
  "description": "<description given while creating job>",
  "projectId": "<project_id>",
  "transferSpec": {
    "gcsDataSink": {
      "bucketName": "<destination_bucket>"
    },
    "objectConditions": {
      "includePrefixes": [
        "<prefix given while creating job>"
      ],
      "lastModifiedSince": "2021-06-30T18:30:00Z"
    },
    "transferOptions": {
      
    },
    "azureBlobStorageDataSource": {
      "storageAccount": "<account_name>",
      "container": "<container_name>"
    }
  },
  "schedule": {
    "scheduleStartDate": {
      "year": 2021,
      "month": 7,
      "day": 1
    },
    "startTimeOfDay": {
      "hours": 13,
      "minutes": 45
    },
    "repeatInterval": "86400s"
  },
  "status": "ENABLED",
  "creationTime": "2021-07-01T06:08:19.392111916Z",
  "lastModificationTime": "2021-07-01T06:13:32.460934533Z",
  "latestOperationName": "transferOperations/transferJobs-<job_name>"
}
```

Now, how do I fetch the run history details of a particular job in python?

By "Run history details" I mean the metrics (Data transferred, no of files, status, size, duration) displayed in GTS console as shown in the picture below.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm unfamiliar with the transfer service but I'm very familiar with GCP.

The only other resource that's provided by the service is [`transferOperations`](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/reference/rest/v1/transferOperations).

Does that provide the data you need?

If not (!), it's possible that Google hasn't exposed this functionality beyond the Console. This happens occasionally even though the intent is always to be (public) API first.

One way you can investigate is to check the browser's developer tools 'network' tab to see what REST API calls the Console is making to fulfill the request. Another way is to use the equivalent `gcloud` command and tack on `--log-http` to see the underlying REST API calls that way.

Answer (score 0):

As @DazWilkin mentioned, I was able to fetch each job's run history details using the [transferOperations - list](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/reference/rest/v1/transferOperations/list) API

I wrote a Cloud Function to fetch GTS metrics by making API calls.
Initially it makes [tansferJobs - list](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/reference/rest/v1/transferJobs/list) API call and fetches the list of jobs and in that fetches only the required job details. It then makes "transferOperations" API call and passes the job name to fetch the run history details.

Here's the code:

```
from googleapiclient import discovery
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
from datetime import datetime

import logging

"""
requirements.txt
google-api-python-client==2.3.0
oauth2client==4.1.3
"""


class GTSMetrics:

    def __init__(self):
        self.project = "<your_gcp_project_name>"
        self.source_type_mapping = {"gcsDataSource": "Google Cloud Storage", "awsS3DataSource": "Amazon S3",
                                    "azureBlobStorageDataSource": "Azure Storage"}
        self.transfer_job_names = ["transferJobs/<your_job_name>"]
        self.credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
        self.service = discovery.build('storagetransfer', 'v1', credentials=self.credentials)
        self.metric_values = {}

    def build_run_history_metrics(self, job=None):
        try:
            if job:
                operation_filters = {"projectId": self.project, "jobNames": [job['name']]}

                request = self.service.transferOperations().list(name='transferOperations', filter=operation_filters)

                while request is not None:
                    response = request.execute()
                    if 'operations' in response:

                        self.metric_values['total_runs'] = len(response['operations'])

                        metadata = response['operations'][0]['metadata']

                        status = metadata['status'] if 'status' in metadata else ""
                        start_time = metadata['startTime'] if 'startTime' in metadata else ""
                        end_time = metadata['endTime'] if 'endTime' in metadata else ""

                        start_time_object = datetime.strptime(start_time[:-4], "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f")
                        end_time_object = datetime.strptime(end_time[:-4], "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f")
                        gts_copy_duration = end_time_object - start_time_object

                        self.metric_values['latest_run_status'] = status
                        self.metric_values['latest_run_time'] = str(start_time_object)
                        self.metric_values['latest_run_errors'] = ""
                        self.metric_values['start_time'] = str(start_time_object)
                        self.metric_values['end_time'] = str(end_time_object)
                        self.metric_values['duration'] = gts_copy_duration.total_seconds()

                        if status == "FAILED":
                            if 'errorBreakdowns' in metadata:
                                errors = metadata['errorBreakdowns'][0]['errorCount']
                                error_code = metadata['errorBreakdowns'][0]['errorCode']
                                self.metric_values['latest_run_errors'] = f"{errors} - {error_code}"
                        elif status == "SUCCESS":
                            counters = metadata['counters']
                            data_bytes = counters['bytesCopiedToSink'] if 'bytesCopiedToSink' in counters else '0 B'
                            obj_from_src = str(
                                counters['objectsFoundFromSource']) if 'objectsFoundFromSource' in counters else 0
                            obj_copied_sink = str(
                                counters['objectsCopiedToSink']) if 'objectsCopiedToSink' in counters else 0
                            data_skipped_bytes = counters[
                                'bytesFromSourceSkippedBySync'] if 'bytesFromSourceSkippedBySync' in counters else '0 B'
                            data_skipped_files = counters[
                                'objectsFromSourceSkippedBySync'] if 'objectsFromSourceSkippedBySync' in counters else '0'

                            self.metric_values['data_transferred'] = data_bytes
                            self.metric_values['files_found_in_source'] = obj_from_src
                            self.metric_values['files_copied_to_sink'] = obj_copied_sink
                            self.metric_values['data_skipped_in_bytes'] = data_skipped_bytes
                            self.metric_values['data_skipped_files'] = data_skipped_files

                    break
                    # request = self.service.transferOperations().list_next(previous_request=request,
                    #                                                       previous_response=response)

        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(f"Exception in build_run_history_metrics - {str(e)}")

    def build_job_metrics(self, job):
        try:
            transfer_spec = list(job['transferSpec'].keys())

            source = ""
            source_type = ""
            if "gcsDataSource" in transfer_spec:
                source_type = self.source_type_mapping["gcsDataSource"]
                source = job['transferSpec']["gcsDataSource"]["bucketName"]
            elif "awsS3DataSource" in transfer_spec:
                source_type = self.source_type_mapping["awsS3DataSource"]
                source = job['transferSpec']["awsS3DataSource"]["bucketName"]
            elif "azureBlobStorageDataSource" in transfer_spec:
                source_type = self.source_type_mapping["azureBlobStorageDataSource"]

            frequency = "Once"
            schedule = list(job['schedule'].keys())
            if "repeatInterval" in schedule:
                interval = job['schedule']['repeatInterval']

                if interval == "86400s":
                    frequency = "Every day"
                elif interval == "604800s":
                    frequency = "Every week"
                else:
                    frequency = "Custom"

            prefix = ""
            if 'objectConditions' in transfer_spec:
                obj_con = job['transferSpec']['objectConditions']
                if 'includePrefixes' in obj_con:
                    prefix = job['transferSpec']['objectConditions']['includePrefixes'][0]

            self.metric_values['job_description'] = job['description']
            self.metric_values['job_name'] = job['name']
            self.metric_values['source_type'] = source_type
            self.metric_values['source'] = source
            self.metric_values['destination'] = job['transferSpec']['gcsDataSink']['bucketName']
            self.metric_values['frequency'] = frequency
            self.metric_values['prefix'] = prefix
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(f"Exception in build_job_metrics - {str(e)}")

    def build_metrics(self):
        try:
            request = self.service.transferJobs().list(pageSize=None, pageToken=None, x__xgafv=None,
                                                       ilter={"projectId": self.project})

            while request is not None:
                response = request.execute()

                for transfer_job in response['transferJobs']:
                    if transfer_job['name'] in self.transfer_job_names:
                        
                        # fetch job details
                        self.build_job_metrics(job=transfer_job)

                        # fetch run history details for the job
                        self.build_run_history_metrics(job=transfer_job)

                request = self.service.transferJobs().list_next(previous_request=request, previous_response=response)

            logging.info(f"GTS Metrics - {str(self.metric_values)}")
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(f"Exception in build_metrics - {str(e)}")


def build_gts_metrics(request):
    gts_metrics = GTSMetrics()
    gts_metrics.build_metrics()
```